# Mixed Content Over HTML form mailto

Tags: html, forms, ssl-certificate, mailto, mixed-content

I would like to solve this issue at my webpage.

The following error appears when I inspect webpage using chrome developer tools: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www....#' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'mailto:contact@example.app'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

This issue occurs by the following command line:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="mailto::contact@example.app" method="post" target="_top">
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, removing mailto from form and using another approach, as use some send mail function from php.

Mailto is not supported in secure connection.